# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword WHERE at [4:1] in BigQuery

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I want to get the following output by executing SQL query, my table name is `customer_data.customer_purchase`

| row | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fan |
| 2 | fan |
| 3 | bed |

I tried to execute the following SQL, but I received this error `Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword WHERE at [4:1]`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    'customer_data.customer_purchase' LIMIT 1000
WHERE 
    product='fan';
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your query and error message as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIMIT` is applied to a whole query's results, not to just one table.

As `SQL` sets are unordered *(a multitude of factors can cause the set to be read in different orders)*, you should also specify an `ORDER BY`, whih goes ***after*** the `WHERE`.

This means that you need something like...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  yourTable.product='fan'
ORDER BY
  yourTable.something
LIMIT
  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    'customer_data.customer_purchase' 
WHERE 
    product='fan'

LIMIT 1000;
```